# How can I modify context.xml of Tomcat on aws opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I want to add this code in /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/context.xml :

```
<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
   sticky="true"
   memcachedNodes="n1:<%= node['redis']['host']%>:<%= node['redis']['port']%>"
   requestUriIgnorePattern=".*.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
/>
```

I'm using Chef 11.4, I've created custom cookbook and modify /opsworks_java/templates/default/webapp_context.xml.erb

But it doesnt work.
It worked for other file: server.xml!

How can i do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution
I've created a template of the context.xml file:
 opsworks-cookbooks/opsworks_java/templates/default/context.xml.erb

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
          sticky="true"
          memcachedNodes="n1:<%= node['redis']['host']%>:<%= node['redis']['port']%>"
          requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"   />
</Context>
```

then i call it in opsworks-cookbooks/opsworks_java/recipes/tomcat_container_config.rb
by adding the following lines:

```
template 'tomcat context configuration' do
  path ::File.join(node['opsworks_java']['tomcat']['catalina_base_dir'], 'context.xml')
  source 'context.xml.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0644
  backup false
  notifies :restart, 'service[tomcat]'
end
```

And it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chef 11.10 it's simple :

1. You need to create / use custom cookbook .
2. In it make the following folder structure :

   opsworks_java/templates/default/
3. Duplicate the file :
   https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_java/templates/default/webapp_context.xml.erb
4. edit it as required.

This will do what you're needing to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im using 11.4. This is exactly what i have done but it doesnt work whith this file. I think webapp_context.xml.erb is not the script that generate context.xml !